# Android Notification stops updating after a certain time

Tags: android, timer, notifications, android-notifications

In my App i am using the `TimerTask` with an `Interval` of 1s. If the App is in the background, I show the current Time in the `NotificationBar`. So every second in the `onTick()` Method I update the silent `Notification`. But with Android 10 it stops updating after few minutes. All `Notifications` are blocked, also the other channels.

Is there a new permission or another way to show the Time in the `NotificationBar`?

Answer (score 2):

your application might be killed in background so that's why it stops showing the updates.

Try using workmanager for your app to run continuously below is the links

[workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

Key features:

- Backwards compatible up to API 14
- Uses JobScheduler on devices with API 23+
- Uses a combination of BroadcastReceiver + AlarmManager on devices
  with API 14-22
- Add work constraints like network availability or charging status
- Schedule asynchronous one-off or periodic tasks
- Monitor and manage scheduled tasks
- Chain tasks together
- Ensures task execution, even if the app or device restarts
- Adheres to power-saving features like Doze mode

Comment: For now I can say it is a Samsung problem. With many other Phone from other Companies it works fine, just Samsung not. Again...